# Prioritize one row over another in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, filter, union

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/41Y3CYgrnLxc4BRPPFp9NZ/3)

```
create table items (
  name varchar(15) not null,
  id1 integer,
  id2 integer,
  UNIQUE(id1),
  UNIQUE(id2)
);

insert into items (name, id1, id2) values 
('a', 1, null),
('b', 2, null),
('c', null, 2);

select * from items where id1=2
union
select * from items where id2=2
and id2 not in (select id2 from items where id1=2);
```

I have a table where there are multiple fields containing the unique id belonging to a given item. In my example, either `id1` or `id2` contains this value. My goal would be to only rely on `id2` if the item cannot be found via `id1`. So, I would expect to always get back `b` in my example.

I have managed to get this working via a union, but it seems like a very hacky solution with bad performance. A better solution seems to me is to filter on the client side. What do you think?

Comment: Are those ids with a proper `UNIQUE` constraint, so that you can be certain to get at most one result?

Comment: There might be duplicates as shown in the example, so items with either id set to 2 can happen for both columns.

Comment: Yes, but an id can only occur once *per column*, no?

Comment: I see what you mean, yes, only once per column, updated the example

Comment: Then I'd probably go for `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id1 = 2 OR id2 = 2 ORDER BY id1 NULLS LAST LIMIT 1`. But make sure to check the query plan to assert it's using the indices, otherwise use the `UNION` instead of `OR` (but with the same `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(id1, id2) ORDER BY id1) rn
    FROM items
)

SELECT name, id1, id2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Each logical pair of records is described by `COALESCE(id1, id2)` being the same between them (if a pair exists).  Within each pair, we choose the record having the *lowest* `id1` value, which would mean the non null record.

Comment: Where's the `id[1|2] = 2` condition?

Comment: I'm not convinced that restriction should be there.  It appears nowhere in the text description.

Comment: Hm, I was under the clear expression that the OP was trying to find one item by id…

Comment: @Bergi Then we can add `WHERE COALESCE(id1, id2) = 2` to the CTE in my answer, and the same logic should work.

Comment: The logic, yes, but would that use the indices on those columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM items WHERE id1 = 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM items WHERE id1 = 2) AS q
ORDER BY id2 IS NULL
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

That relies on the fact that `FALSE < TRUE`.